# webDriver cssSelector based on inner child attribute

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors

here is some sample code and what I am trying to do:

```
<dl id="parentId">
    <dt>
        <a someattr="whatIwant"/>
    </dt>
    <dt>
        <a someattr="whatIwantNextTime"/>
   </dt>
</dl
```

I am trying to select the a element with someattr="whatIwant". this is my current cssselector:

```
"dl[id='parentId']>a[someattr='whatIwant']"
```

as well as:

```
"dl[id='parentId']>dt>a[someattr='whatIwant']"
```

Unfortunately, neither of these work; I appear to be following the w3schools template correctly, however I get element cannot be found exceptions when I try to run this, or illegal string exception if I add the '>dt>'. Does anyone have any insight on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  You are using the direct descendant selector strategy (`>`) this only works if the element is a direct child.  If you want a descenant of, use ()

```
dl#parentId a[someattr='whatIwant']
```

Also, assuming that your `whatIwant` is unique, then this selector will work perfectly..

Even further, you can do:

```
dl#parentId > td:nth-child(X) > a
```

where `X` is 1, 2, 3 (the index of the `<dt />` that you want.

Also make sure that you are using the `By.cssSelector` strategy and nothing else if you are specifying CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I didn't do enough research, as I just figured this out 5 minutes after posting. The descendent selector ' ' works perfectly, which is:

```
"dl[id='parentId'] a[someattr='whatIwant']"
```